# Infinite vs. Limited Use Incubators

Tags: pokemon-go

Is there any advantage to incubating an egg with the infinite use incubator, or the limited uses incubators? Are CP values or rarity of the hatched pokemon affected by the type of incubator used?

Comment: The only reason you would even use the limited use incubators is to hatch multiple pokemon at same time. You are literally multiplying your eggs per km walked with each additional incubator. That seems like it's a good enough incentive to use them...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is no difference between hatching with each incubator.
However, if you want to get the most out of your temporary incubators, it is recommended that you try to only hatch 10km or 5km eggs in the temporary ones (preferring 10km). Doing this will allow you to be hatching more eggs at a time.

Comment: Or if you have only 2km eggs and just want to get rid of them in 1 go

Comment: @Kiwi: Sure, you could obviously do that, but that's a sub-optimal use of the temporary incubators. Since they expire based on how often you use them, using them on 2km eggs means you only get 6km of walking out of them before you need to replace them. Conversely, using them on 3 10km eggs nets you 30km of walking. So, I pretty much only use the infinite incubator to hatch 2km eggs.

Comment: @Ellesedil: I'm using them to hatch 2km eggs because I only have 2km eggs, and I don't see a way to throw eggs away

Comment: @Ellesedil - Is that still the case when you have _only_ 2km eggs left? Should you still wait for a 5/10km egg even though that may take a while to get rid of all the 2km eggs?

Comment: @DMan: That's a judgement call on your part. If you have only one temporary incubator, I'd personally keep it for a 5 or 10 km egg. If you have several, well, are you willing to exchange less total distance for more eggs? This might also depend on just how much walking you can do. *shrugs* There's several variables to consider in a situation like that, and some variables will more more important to some people than others.

Comment: I think there's a 9-egg limit, right? So if you had nine 2 km eggs, you can't get any more 5 km or 10 km eggs until you hatch some fo the 2 km ones, so that would be a situation where using purchased incubators helps maximize egg hatching. To me, hatching eggs is so advantagous that even though I try to save the free incubator for 2 km eggs, if it's already in use and I get a 2 km egg, I'll use a paid inclubator on it just to keep the production line moving along.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no indication of different results using different incubators.

Comment: Is this backed up by any information? Just claiming no isn't really answering my question.

Comment: I can tell you the same out of experience.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf the game code has been decompiled and run through, and there has been nothing showing that one type of incubator is favored.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf As Andrew mentions, I get my conclusion from the source code.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any difference! Although I see a lot of people saying they do not like 2km eggs. Here is a bit of info for you: yesterday my boyfriend offered to walk around the block to hatch my 2km egg and he waiting for me to crack it open (I didn't want to walk anymore we had just went for a 10km walk for a different egg) Well as that 10km only got me a Zubat, the 2km gave me a Pikachu. I was very very very surprised and excited. I used my infinite use on the 2km and the limited use on the 10km. It is purely just luck everyone!! ☺️

Comment: I'm confused, Zubat don't come from 10km eggs... They are only in 2km eggs.

Answer (score 3):

I'm late to this conversation. I think the best is to use infinite use incubator for 2km or the shortest distance eggs you have on hand and use limited use incubators for 10km or the longer distance eggs you have on hand. Let say you have one 2km egg and one 10km egg with one infinite incubator and one limited use incubator with one use left. If you put the 10km in the infinite incubator, after the 2km egg hatched and limited use incubator is used up, you'll have to wait until the 10km egg hatched to free up the infinite incubator unless you buy more incubators. While the vice versa will free up your infinite incubator quickly for the next egg.

Comment: It's okay that you're late! Your answer is helpful and is a reasonable suggestion. This is how I use my incubators, as well. Oh, and welcome to Arqade!

Comment: I'm glad I am not the only one who finds this as a great approach. It's very inefficient to use a limited-use incubator for a Pidgey

Comment: @Wondercricket, pidgey and rattata were removed from the 2k egg pool recently. Eevee also got moved to the 5k pool instead of the 10k one

Comment: Thanks for the info Mic! Although I don't play this game anymore, it definitely helps others!

Comment: Thank you all for the warm welcome. Sad to hear you're not playing anymore Kaizerwolf. I know a lot of people have left the game. I'm still hanging in there hoping to catch all the Pokémons. :)

Answer (score 0):

The best use for a limited use is for a 10k egg. This is because you can then hatch your smaller eggs while waiting for your 10k egg to hatch at the same time.